# Prove that a convex pentagon(that is a pentagon whose all diagonals lie in the figure)has three diagonals which can form a triangle.

Tags: geometry

Prove that a convex pentagon(that is a pentagon whose all diagonals lie in the figure)has three diagonals which can form a triangle.
My solution goes as follow:

We consider the longest diahonals and it is given that the diagonals lie inside the pentagon, so we can say there is a point on one of the two sides of diagonal into which it divides the pentagon into. And this point forms two pairs of points, one with one end of the diagonal and the other with other end of the diagonal . Thus, those three points form a triangle inside the pentagon.

I just want to verify my solution whether it is correct or not...

Comment: I feel like "three diagonals which can form a triangle" means "can form a triangle whose side lengths are the lengths of the diagonals," rather than "the diagonals in the pentagon intersect to form a small triangle [that may not use the full lengths of each diagonal]."

Comment: @angryavian Well, that may be true...but even if we have a vertex then we can that vertex with the two endpoints of the long diagonal...and we can still get a triangle by three diagonals...